# SQL: Calculate percentage in other table, and user percentage to filter?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables. The first one, called 'users' looks like this:

```
id | Username
----------------------
1  | time
2  | bill
3  | jeff
```

The second one, called 'posts' looks like this:

```
id | user | category
----------------------
1  | bill | 3
2  | tim  | 1
3  | bill | 3
4  | bill | 2
```

Each different number in the categories column corresponds to a category.

---

I'm attempting to create a SQL query that will get all the users who have more than 10% of their posts in a specific category. Here's what my current (not working) code looks like for category 3:

```
SELECT 
    u.Username, 
    (
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts WHERE user=u.Username AND category=3) 
        / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts WHERE user=u.Username) 
        * 100
    ) AS percentage 
FROM users u 
WHERE percentage > 10
```

This query should in theory return 'bill'. However, it doesn't work! Do I have a syntax error somewhere, or is my method bad/wrong?

Comment: what does 'it doesn't work!' mean?

Comment: From the posts below, I believe it was because of my 'percentage' being in the where column.

Comment: That still doesn't say what problem you were having.  Did it blow up?  Return 42?  or 'Orange'?  It didn't work, but what *did* it do?  Not relevant now, but please try to say next time you have a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percentage alias can't exist within where clause. You have to use having clause.

```
SELECT 
    u.Username, 
    (
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts WHERE user=u.Username AND category=3) 
        / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts WHERE user=u.Username) 
        * 100
    ) AS percentage 
FROM users u 
HAVING percentage > 10
```

Comment: Thanks for the accepted answer but The Scrum Meister's query is much better. I've just told you your mistake without spending any time to improve it as he did. :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using all those subqueries, you can query the `posts` table directly:

```
SELECT Username,
    (SUM(Category = 3) / COUNT(*)) * 100 AS percentage 
FROM posts
GROUP BY 1
HAVING percentage > 10
```